# Calculating the volume soild of revolution made with a function and its tangent

Tags: integration, proof-verification, solid-of-revolution

> A tangent of the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$ at point Q crosses the point P(-1,0). What is the volume of the solid of revolution when the area bounded by the line PQ, $y=\sqrt{x}$ and the x-axis is rotated through 2$\pi$ about the x-axis?

**My approach:**

Setting the x-coordinate of point Q as $a$, then Q($a$,$\sqrt{a}$)

The equation of the tangent can be written as 
$$y-\sqrt{a}={{1}\over{2\sqrt{a}}}(x-a)$$
Substituting $x=-1$ and $y=0$ into the equation,
$$-\sqrt{a} = {{-1-a}\over{2\sqrt{a}}}$$
$$-2a  = -1-a$$
therefore $a=1$

Now point Q(1,1) can be used to come up with an equation for the line PQ,
which is $$y={{1}\over{2}}(x+1)$$
Then, the volume $V$ can be calculated as 
$$V=\pi\int^1_{-1}\left({{1}\over{2}}(x+1)\right)^2-(\sqrt{x})^2\ dx$$
$$=\pi\int^1_{-1}{{1}\over{4}}(x+1)^2-x\ dx$$
$$=\pi\int^1_{-1}{{1}\over{4}}(x^2+2x+1)-x\ dx$$
$$=\pi\int^1_{-1}{{1}\over{4}}x^2-{{1}\over{2}}x+{{1}\over{4}}\ dx$$
$$=\pi\left[{{1}\over{12}}x^3-{{1}\over{4}}x^2+{{1}\over{4}}x\right]^1_{-1}$$
which returns ${2\pi}\over{3}$.

Did I do this question correctly?

Comment: No. The integral you wrote makes sense for the portion in the first quadrant only ($0\leq x\leq 1$). The triangular shape in the second quadrant generates a cone when rotated.

Comment: Does adding the volume of the cone to the value I found in the question return the correct answer then?

Comment: No. $\int _0^1\pi \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^2-x\right)dx$ added to the cone would work. You could use cylindrical shells instead

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your work insofar as the limits of integration on the $\sqrt{x}$-term is incorrect. This should be $x\in[0,1]$, as seen in the figure below. Thus we have

$$
\begin{align}
V
&=\pi\left(\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2} \right)^2~dx -\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}^2~dx \right)\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{(x+1)^3}{3\cdot4} \biggr|_{-1}^1 + \frac{x^2}{2}\biggr|_0^1\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align}
$$

I have verified this result numerically.

[image: Sqrt & Tangent]